# Creating one-to-one RESTful API relationship

Tags: web-services, rest, http, web

I need to create a one-to-one relationship between a `Game` and a `Site` - each game happens in one site. In my database, `site` is an attribute of the Game object which points to a `Site` object.

I couldn't find much on the internet about this, these are my ideas:

```
GET /game/<game_id>/site
```

Gets a game's site, hiding the site id.

```
POST /game/<game_id>/site
```

Creates a game's site, this is only used once when creating the game.

```
PUT /game/<game_id>/site
```

Updates a game's site

```
DELETE /game/<game_id>/site
```

Deletes a game's site.

But what if someone wants to get a list of all the sites? Should I add a `/sites` URI and have the `get` method for the `Site` object detect whether a `game_id` has been passed in? Should I also let people access a site by `/sites/<site_id>` Or should I let the client populate their own list of `sites` by iterating over all `games`? Finally, I usually have an 'href' attribute for each object which is a link back to itself. If I went with the above design (incl. the `/sites/` URI), do I link to `/game/<game_id>/site` or `/sites/<site_id>`? Should there be two places to access the same info?

Am I on the right track? Or is there a better way to model one-to-one relationships in REST?

If it matters, I'm using Flask-RESTful to make my APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Your ideas make a lot of sense.

The big distinction is whether or not a `site` can exist independently of a `game`. It sounds like it can. For example, two games may point to the same site.

As far as I understand with RESTful API design, there isn't a problem with exposing the same `site` resource through both `/game/<game_id>/site` and through `/sites/<side_id>`. But REST encourages you to link data through hypermedia.

Exposing the `site` in two different places could complicate things, since you'd then expect to be able to interact with site objects through both of those URLs.

My recommendation to keep your structure explicit and simple would be:

- Have a collection of site resources at `/sites`
- Expose `site` resources at `/site/<site_id>`
- Use a **link object** from a `game` to a `site`. See [Thoughts on RESTful API design by Geert Jansen](http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/restful-api-design/latest/restful-api-design.pdf).

Following the link object design, your `game` resource representation would include something like this:

```
{
  "game_id": 10,
  ...,
  "link": {
    rel: resource/site
    href: /api/sites/14
  }
}
```

Without more design work, this would mean you'll make a second call to get the site's information. Every design has its compromises :)